# Parts numbering in Proofs

Tags: numbering, theorems, amsthm

I am using `proof` environment from `amsthm` to type proofs. Some proofs are long, so it would be nice to split them into numbered parts. I have defined new theorem environment called `proofpart` for that purpose.

The problem is that the `proofpart` counter does not reset inside a new proof and continues to grow. So I wonder how the counter can be reset for such case.

Sample document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}


\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{proofpart}{Part}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}
  \begin{theorem}
    Some theorem
  \end{theorem}

  \begin{proof}
    Proof of some theorem
    \begin{proofpart} % 1
      First part 
    \end{proofpart}
    \begin{proofpart} % 2
      Second part
    \end{proofpart}
  \end{proof}


  \begin{theorem}
    Another theorem
  \end{theorem}

  \begin{proof}
    Proof of another theorem
    \begin{proofpart} % 3, but should be 1
      First part
    \end{proofpart}
    \begin{proofpart} % 4, but should be 2
      Second part
    \end{proofpart}
  \end{proof}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi. There is no need to say "thanks" in your posts. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say thank you to those who helped you. This takes time getting used to but one way in which this site maintains less noise. [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One option would be to use `\@addtoreset`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{proofpart}{Part}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{proofpart}{theorem}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  \begin{theorem}
    Some theorem
  \end{theorem}

  \begin{proof}
    Proof of some theorem
    \begin{proofpart} % 1
      First part 
    \end{proofpart}
    \begin{proofpart} % 2
      Second part\qedhere
    \end{proofpart}
  \end{proof}


  \begin{theorem}
    Another theorem
  \end{theorem}

  \begin{proof}
    Proof of another theorem
    \begin{proofpart} % it is 1
      First part
    \end{proofpart}
    \begin{proofpart} % it is 2
      Second part\qedhere
    \end{proofpart}
  \end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A little description taken from `source2e`:

> `\@addtoreset{foo}{bar} : Adds counter`foo`to the list of counters`
>   \cl@bar`to be reset when counter`bar` is stepped.

Another option (suggested by **Werner**) would be to use the second optional argument for `\newtheorem` in the definition of `proofpart` (this requires defining this structure **after** the `theorem` environment) and a redefinition of the representation of the associated counter:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{proofpart}{Part}[theorem]
\renewcommand\theproofpart{\arabic{proofpart}}

\begin{document}
  \begin{theorem}
    Some theorem
  \end{theorem}

  \begin{proof}
    Proof of some theorem
    \begin{proofpart} % 1
      First part 
    \end{proofpart}
    \begin{proofpart} % 2
      Second part\qedhere
    \end{proofpart}
  \end{proof}


  \begin{theorem}
    Another theorem
  \end{theorem}

  \begin{proof}
    Proof of another theorem
    \begin{proofpart} % it is 1
      First part
    \end{proofpart}
    \begin{proofpart} % it is 2
      Second part\qedhere
    \end{proofpart}
  \end{proof}

\end{document}
```

`\newtheorem{env-name}{doc-name}[counter]`, where `counter` is an existing or previouly defined counter, causes the `env-name` counter to be reset whenever the parent counter `counter` is incremented; however, the label will have the  `counter` number pre-pended, so a redefinition of the representation is needed to suppress the pre-pendend string.

I also used `\qedhere` to correct the end-mark position.