# How to split theorem proofs into numbered parts?

Tags: theorems

In theorem proofs, I would like to use numbered parts. For example,

> Theorem 1. Blabla.
>
> Proof.
>
> Part 1. blabla
>
> Part 1.1. Blabla
>
> Part 2
>
> Part 2.1
>
> Part 2.2

This is different from [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/101880/parts-numbering-in-proofs) since it has only one level in that question.

Comment: this is not good idea. you're going to mess up the structure of your document. just my opinion ...

Comment: @Zarko I do not mean the same section as in `\section`. I mean just splitting the proof into multiple parts.

Comment: try to use some nested lists, for example accordingly modified  `description` . for more specific advice please provide what you tray so far, the best in form of small but complete document begining with `\documentclass{...}`, followed by preamble (only with packages which are relevant to page layout and your problem) and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Too many nested levels in a proof is IMHO a really poor writing. If your theorem _do_ need many steps to be proved and each step takes many space, you can use a structure called “Lemma”. They are literally “building blocks” of the main theorem and will make your article more well-structured.

Comment: @Zarko Currently I have only used itemized lists. However, the boundaries of ends of subitems are not so obvious in the document.

Comment: Why not introducing a couple of lemmas?

Comment: @RuixiZhang Thanks for your advice. I only want to reach the subpart level, which is one level deeper than the given link. I have already extracted as many lemmata as possible and the proof is in moderate length, and I determined that splitting into parts in this case is better than creating more redundant and lengthy lemmata.

Comment: As  @Zarko, I would use some type of `description` environment, or an  `enumerate` with a prefix to the counter. This is easily customised with `enumitem`.

Comment: In some math paper, it is common to use a (sub)section `\(sub)section{Proof of Theorem~\ref{thm}}` and therein you write everything you want.